# Why is my ISO so high in auto mode?

Tags: autofocus, iso

New user of a Canon 7D - less than 50 shots taken.
Last night, I needed to take a quick picture of something that was on my cell phone with my Canon 7D

I propped the phone up against a white pillow in a very well lit room.  I zoomed in to just focus on the screen while in full AUTO / Green mode.  ISO was showing 7200 and the exposure light wouldn't stop flashing, so I couldn't take the photo.  Any ideas why this happened?  Something about potentially being too close to the source?  There was bright light in the room - and the flash didn't pop.

I tried recomposing - still had no luck.  I WAS able to take pictures of other things in the room.  I eventually just flipped to CA and took the shot.

Is this normal behavior - Why did the camera choose an ISO that wouldn't allow for the shot to be taken, rather than using the flash? And auto-focus squares were clearly lighting up.

Comment: What mode was your 7D set to when you first attempted to take the shot?

Comment: I was shooting in full auto / green mode initially

Comment: Ah, I hardly shoot with my 7D set to the full auto mode. Will experiment when I'm at home later to see if I can duplicate what you saw.

Comment: What lens were you using and what focal length was it at?

Comment: My guess is that you were at too close of a focusing distance. I would try stepping back. If we knew what lens you were using we could recommend the distance it will focus at a minimum. Also, ISO 7200 isn't that high for a 7D indoors without a flash. Was this at night or during the day(with windows?)

Comment: I don't know about 7D, but generally on at least prosumer and professional DSLRs the built-in flash won't automatically activate just because there is insufficient light; you have to activate it yourself. This is almost certainly because unexpected use of the flash can have huge downsides, and the built-in flash isn't strong enough to make a big difference in a lot of situations anyway (and many times when it does make a difference, the effects aren't what the photographer wanted unless they were conscious about it). Think "flash light falloff".

Answer (score 2):

Never seen a camera not shoot because of exposure and I've had a Canon 7D too. I did not like how it metered by default and photos were more often over-exposed than with other cameras but it still took the shot.

A camera refused to shoot though if it cannot focus. You were probably too close and the camera light up *all* focus points as opposed to *some* to let you know. All lenses have a minimum focus distance which is usually specified at the wide-angle settings. Some also specify it at another distance and it should be stated in the manual.

The other case when a camera can refuse to shoot is if the flash is still charging. In this case you just have to wait a little before releasing the shutter and there should be a light to tell you when.

The Auto ISO chooses a sensitivity to get an exposure is deemed acceptable (even though you or I may disagree) at a shutter-speed which is safe to hand-hold. There is a maximum but I do not remember which it is for the 7D.

Comment: Just a pedantic clarification. A 7D will refuse to shoot if it cannot focus using One Shot AF.  However for those of us who e.g. have it set to use Back Button Focussing and AI-Servo, it will happily take a shot without confirming focus.

Comment: The 7D v2 firmware includes menu support for limiting the max ISO that the camera will choose in Auto ISO.  A 7D bought in the last 6 months at least should have the v2 firmware.

Comment: Yes, obviously customization can change this to *Release-Priority* as opposed to *Focus-Priority*, something I do not expect someone have taken 50 shots to have time to change yet :)

Comment: In Auto (green) mode by default the focus mode is set to AI Focus only and can not be changed. AI Servo custom settings would not apply in Auto mode.